# When is a bash script passes to 'openstack server create --user-data ...' exactly executed?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I have a bash script that I want to be executed before a user can login to the server. I cannot find any information on when this script is exactly executed for different images. Can I assume that this is before a user is able to login using ssh? I'm using cirros.

```sh
openstack server create --user-data before_login.sh ...
```

Comment: For cirros specifically check out `/etc/init.d/cirros-userdata` and follow the bouncing ball

Answer (score 1):

As soon as your instance boots up this user-data script "before_login.sh" executes on it before any user login into the instance.

Answer (score 0):

User-scripts run at final stage, this stage runs as late in boot as possible. Any scripts that a user is accustomed to running after logging into a system should run correctly here.

You can check below link for cloud-int behaviors for more information
https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/boot.html